# Can I send webrequest from specified ip address with .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, ip-address, webrequest

I have a server with multi ip addresses. Now I need to communicate with several servers with http protocol. Each server only accept the request from a specified ip address of my server. But when using WebRequest(or HttpWebRequest) in .NET , the request object will choose a ip address automatically. I can't find anyway to bind the request with a address.

Is there anyway to do so ? Or I have to implement a webrequest class myself ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use the `ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate` callback.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/malarch/archive/2005/09/13/466664.aspx

> The delegate is called before the socket associated with the httpwebrequest attempts to connect to the remote end.

```
public static IPEndPoint BindIPEndPointCallback(ServicePoint servicePoint, IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, int retryCount)
{
    Console.WriteLine("BindIPEndpoint called");
      return new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,5000);

}

public static void Main()
{

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://MyServer");

    request.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = new BindIPEndPoint(BindIPEndPointCallback);

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

}
```

Comment: Amazing. The problem just got resolved in such a simple way! Thanks, Sam.

Comment: I don't recommend setting the port to 5000. This can cause timeouts if you are making requests with multiple instances on this port. Instead, I would set the port to 0 and let the tcp layer handle the connections, which will always be through port 80 anyway.

Comment: It works fine on .NET Framework but doesn't work on .NET Core and I don't know why.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do this using `WebClient` you'll need to subclass it:

```
var webClient = new WebClient2(IPAddress.Parse("10.0.0.2"));
```

and the subclass:

```
public class WebClient2 : WebClient
{
    public WebClient2(IPAddress ipAddress) {
        _ipAddress = ipAddress;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = (WebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);

        ((HttpWebRequest)request).ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate += (servicePoint, remoteEndPoint, retryCount) => {

            return new IPEndPoint(_ipAddress, 0);
        };

        return request;
    }
}
```

(thanks @Samuel for the all important ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate part)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether you read this post (?)

[How to specify server IP in HttpWebRequest](http://yoursunny.com/t/2009/HttpWebRequest-IP/)

or

[Specifying Source IP of HttpWebRequest](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxnetcom/thread/302af808-8184-4527-9527-83bc231954df)