# VB.net proxy exception

Tags: vb.net, proxy, webbrowser-control

My code using proxy works but when the proxy is invalid or restricted my program directly uses my IP address, i used a web browser that directly checks my ip, is there any way that i could set an exception  whenever the proxy i used is invalid or restricted?

here is my working code:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices 
   #Region "Using Proxy"
        <Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
        Private Shared Function InternetSetOption(ByVal hInternet As IntPtr, ByVal dwOption As Integer, ByVal lpBuffer As IntPtr, ByVal lpdwBufferLength As Integer) As Boolean
        End Function

        Public Structure Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO
            Public dwAccessType As Integer
            Public proxy As IntPtr
            Public proxyBypass As IntPtr
        End Structure

        Private Sub UseProxy(ByVal strProxy As String)
            Const INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY As Integer = 38
            Const INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY As Integer = 3

            Dim struct_IPI As Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO

            struct_IPI.dwAccessType = INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY
            struct_IPI.proxy = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(strProxy)
            struct_IPI.proxyBypass = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("local")

            Dim intptrStruct As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI))

            Marshal.StructureToPtr(struct_IPI, intptrStruct, True)

            Dim iReturn As Boolean = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY, intptrStruct, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI))
        End Sub
    #End Region

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    UseProxy(ProxyText.Text)
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("ipchicken.com")

    End Sub
```

Comment: Wrap the code for the line(s) that fail in a try-catch block?

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution below:

[Another Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273462/can-i-send-webrequest-from-specified-ip-address-with-net-framework)

I believe if you bind the address to that specific ip it wont work , if the ip is invalid or not working, and wont use your systems default.