# How to use HttpClient to send a Request from a specific IP address? C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, dotnet-httpclient

I have multiple IPs on the server and would like to chose which one of those I want to use when using HttpClient class to get/post data from an API.
(or to even send requests at the same time but utilise the 2 IPs and not just one)

I have seen some examples using HttpWebRequest ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273462/can-i-send-webrequest-from-specified-ip-address-with-net-framework)) that utilises delegate but I would like to carry on using HttpClient implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ This will be a hacky code, because there is no method/property  to access the *ServicePoint* ]

You can use reflection to access the underlying *ServicePoint* as below
 (Since there is no public/private field/property to access this value, I will hook the *startRequest* delegate)

```
HttpClientHandler SetServicePointOptions(HttpClientHandler handler)
{
    var field = handler.GetType().GetField("_startRequest", BindingFlags.NonPublic| BindingFlags.Instance); // Fieldname has a _ due to being private
    var startRequest = (Action<object>)field.GetValue(handler);

    Action<object> newStartRequest = obj =>
    {
        var webReqField = obj.GetType().GetField("webRequest", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var webRequest = webReqField.GetValue(obj) as HttpWebRequest;
        webRequest.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = new BindIPEndPoint(BindIPEndPointCallback);

        startRequest(obj); //call original action
    };

    field.SetValue(handler, newStartRequest); //replace original 'startRequest' with the one above

    return handler;
}
```

*BindIPEndPointCallback* is the one you [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273462/can-i-send-webrequest-from-specified-ip-address-with-net-framework) in your question. Modify it as you wish.
Now you can use this method like

```
HttpClientHandler handler = SetServicePointOptions(new HttpClientHandler());
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
var str = await client.GetStringAsync("https://google.com");
```

Comment: Just to put an update to this, for anyone using this code, don't get caught out like I did.

Firstly with the fact the .net core team have implemented the HttpClientHandler etc without bothering to put anything related to service points in there, so you'll write all your code to find it silently does nothing, not to mention this code in this example while valid will break.

Also speaking of this code the main warning --- the first field name is incorrect it should be _startRequest otherwise you'll get null ref errors & use the full framework not core.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. I had the exact same problem, that setting a servicePoint.bindIpEndPointDelegate did work on .net fx but not on .net core! Finally I had to switch my code to .net fx