# How do I change the "Source IP" of ClientWebSocket and HttpClient (GET, POST) in C #?

Tags: c#, httpclient, vps, clientwebsocket

I am using a `VPS server` with several white IP addresses. I need to make connections to the server using `HttpClient` and `ClientWebSocket` that has a command processing limit set.
How do I **change the source IP in the HttpClient and ClientWebSocket** classes? So that I can increase the amount of requested commands per unit of time.
I connect to `Poloniex / Binance` (in the first and the other, the limit on the number of requests is 6 per second).

alas i am using .Net Framework 4.7.2

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65930192/how-to-bind-httpclient-to-a-specific-source-ip-address-in-net-5

Comment: alas i am using .Net Framework