# Specifying NetworkInterface for HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net-core, network-programming, network-interface

Ive been trying to create a `.NET 6.0` program which uses a specific (Arch) linux network interface to make http requests for 2 days now, ive read [#23267](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23267), tried understanding the code examples provided in it and many stack overflow solutions but none of them worked for me. I am also using IPv6 because for some reason both wlan0 (wifi) and enp3s0 (ethernet) have the same **private** IPv4 even though theyre on different networks, but this is apparently not too uncommon so since the IPv6's arent the same I went with them

Currently this is the code i have:

```cs
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;

foreach (var iface in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{
    if ((iface.Name == "wlan0"))
    {
        );
        foreach (var ua in iface.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
        {
            if (ua.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork) continue; 

            Console.WriteLine($"\x1b[36m{ua.Address.AddressFamily} Address: {ua.Address.ToString().Split("%")[0]}\x1b[0m");

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"http://[{ua.Address}]:0/"); // same thing happens with splitting ua.Address

            try {
                var res = await client.GetAsync("https://ifconfig.me");
                Console.WriteLine(await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            } catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }
        }
    }
}
```

The output of my program:

```
InterNetworkV6 Address: fe80::eaf:aec2:7d24:82d4
***.***.***.27
```

vs the correct wlan0 public IPv4 with `curl --interface wlan0 ifconfig.me`:

```
***.***.***.4
```

The `client.BaseAddress` part seems to do nothing, since i get the same result with and without it even though the IPv6 im specifying in the URI is definitely the wlan0 IPv6. So, trying another solution and rewriting the client:

```cs
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new SocketsHttpHandler() {
    ConnectCallback = async (context, cancellationToken) =>
    {
        Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ua.Address, 0));
        socket.NoDelay = true;
        try
        {
            await socket.ConnectAsync(context.DnsEndPoint, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return new NetworkStream(socket, true);
        }
        catch
        {
            socket.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }
});
```

This makes my program give this output:

```
InterNetworkV6 Address: fe80::eaf:aec2:7d24:82d4
No data available (ifconfig.me:443)
```

Now, testing on my laptop which also has Arch Linux installed, with 2 different wifi adapters where each is connected to a different network and has a unique private IPv4 address; One is a USB adapter and its called `wlp0s20f0u2` and the other is the built in one, called `wlp2s0`. Changing my code from skipping IPv4 addresses to skipping IPv4 (the continue statements) and removing the AddressFamily specification from the Socket initialization - the plugged in adapter works fine and is the default option (gets chosen by a plain `new HttpClient()`) but the built in adapter ends up timing out after the default 100 seconds and i don't see any requests being made in the `wlp2s0` interface through wireshark. This also happened on my PC with IPv4, before i somehow made both private IPv4's the same. And again, `curl --interface wlp2s0 ifconfig.me` works fine

Comment: FYI: `client.BaseAddress` sets the base address for the request. For example: `client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.example.com/test");` when used with `await client.GetAsync("page/here.htm");` would make a request to `https://www.example.com/test/page/here.htm`.

Comment: hm yeah i guessed thats what it does but ive seen some people suggest it as a way to do what im trying to do so thats why i included that here i guess @DiplomacyNotWar

Comment: I've tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66681784/3181933), which seems to be what you based your second example on, and at least over IPv4 it seems to use the correct interface (I checked with Wireshark).

Comment: it might work through ipv4 but sadly ipv6 is the only unique private ip i have between the 2 networks since i havent been able to figure out how to change the private ipv4 for my machine on one of the networks and i think im not able to do it through my routers admin page - also ipv6 might be a more stable option because of this, and im guessing curl used ipv6 too since their --interface specification still works even with 2 of my networks sharing the same private ipv4 @DiplomacyNotWar

Comment: Is https://ifconfig.me definitely available on IPv6? I've put the URL into a few IPv6 validators and it seems that the site isn't IPv6 ready?

Comment: looks like its not but ifconfig.co apparently is and for that one i get "Network is unreachable" for both http and https but it also doesnt work with curl -6 - Couldn't connect to server @DiplomacyNotWar

Comment: what version of .NET are you using? Mono? dotnet? what version?

Comment: i didnt realise i havent specified that, .NET Core 6.0 @user1623521 i updated the post

Comment: Address is an array where on most machines index zero is IPV6 and index one is IPV4.