# Xamarin Forms application - Force IPv4 to HttpClient

Tags: xamarin.forms, dotnet-httpclient, ipv4, servicepointmanager, servicepoint

It appears that this can be achieved by setting up a callback function to the ServicePoint.

The solution (although the goal is different, the same technique can be used) is discussed in this question [Specify the local endpoint for HTTP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67098313/specify-the-local-endpoint-for-http-request).

Following it, I tried

```
var servicePoint = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri(uri));
servicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = (servicePoint, remoteEndPoint, retryCount) =>
{
  if (remoteEndPoint.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
  {
    return new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
  }

  throw new InvalidOperationException("no IPv4 address");
};

var _client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.GetAsync(uri);
```

expecting that the callback is called at the GetAsync() but it is not.

It would be much appreciated if someone tells me what I am missing.
Or, a completely different approach to achieve my goal, to force IPv4 at connections that HttpClient makes, would also be very much welcome.

Thanks in advance for your help.

### Update

In the question [How to use HttpClient to send a Request from a specific IP address? C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39689858/how-to-use-httpclient-to-send-a-request-from-a-specific-ip-address-c-sharp), someone says "... the .net core team have implemented the HttpClientHandler etc without bothering to put anything related to service points in there ..."
To confirm, I build the above code both with Framework4.7 and Core3.1 to find out that indeed, when built with Core, the callback is NOT called.

A Xamarin project targets .Net standard, which is a Core if I am not mistaken. I guess I need to forget this ServicePoint stuff and look for other solutions...

Again, your insight will be very much appreciated!

Comment: 1. Which platform you are trying to force IPv4 to HttpClient? 2. Have you tried to set the break point at  `await _client.GetAsync(uri);` if confirm if it gets there? Also, you can try to use `response = await _client.GetAsync(uri); Console.WriteLine(response);` to see it on the debug output. 3. You can also refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/37385163/9644964 and [Forcing HttpClient to use IPv4 or IPv6 addresses](https://www.meziantou.net/forcing-httpclient-to-use-ipv4-or-ipv6-addresses.htm) to see if you can get some help.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I want to do this on mobile phones, within an app that I am making with Xamarin. Yes, I confirm that the GetAsync() gets executed. [stackoverflow.com/a/37385163/9644964](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384945/how-to-force-ipv6-or-ipv4-for-httpwebrequest-or-webrequest-c-sharp/37385163#37385163) talks about a solution for httpwebrequet rather than httpclient, and another for .Net 5.
[Forcing HttpClient to use IPv4 or IPv6 addresses](https://www.meziantou.net/forcing-httpclient-to-use-ipv4-or-ipv6-addresses.htm) is for .Net 5 too.

Comment: If the latter thread with .Net 5 works, you can try to update to .Net 5 and try to force using IPv4 with HttpClient.

Comment: Thanks Alex. If I am not wrong, it is not possible to upgrade (or change) a Xamarin Forms project to target Net5.